# WordPress - autor privileges issue

Tags: wordpress

This is the contents of functions.php. The code displays for the admin some buttons in the editor. Why are these buttons displayed for the admin, but not displayed for the author?

```
function spectext_button() {
if (current_user_can('edit_posts') && current_user_can('edit_pages'))
{
    add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'spectext_plugin');
    add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'spectext_register_button');
}
}
add_action('init', 'spectext_button');

function spectext_plugin($plugin_array){
    $plugin_array['spectext'] = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/newbuttons.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

function spectext_register_button($buttons){
    array_push($buttons, "green");
    array_push($buttons, "yellow");
    array_push($buttons, "red");
    return $buttons;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&& current_user_can('edit_pages')`

The above mentioned code checks if the user has the privileges to edit pages which is allowed to only following user roles:

- Super Administrator
- Administrator
- Editor

If you remove this condition your buttons will work for all users capable of editing posts i.e.

- Super Administrator
- Administrator
- Editor
- Author
- Contributor

Comment: I remove this condition, fixed the author's rights with the plug-in User Role Editor. None of this helped.

Comment: '/js/newbuttons.js' began to load after I changed the operator '|| current_user_can('edit_pages')' but buttons are still not displayed

Comment: @ОлегНечаев try changing `add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'spectext_register_button');` to this `add_filter('mce_buttons', 'spectext_register_button');`

Comment: It works! Thank you! Can you explain why add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'spectext_register_button'); doesn't work?

Comment: The hook `'mce_buttons_2'` works for advanced toolbar which is toggled off by default(if I am correct).

Comment: How can I toggle it on? Advanced toolbar works for an admin

Comment: I think [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52121/second-toolbar-in-tinymce-has-displaynone-set) should help you out.